Kavacham of deities to protect ourselves from negative,manipulative and bad people
What are some kavachams that will protect the practitioner from bad , negative ,manipulative and deceitful people?
Kavachams of maa Tara,Durga ,batuk bhairava,bhairava are more preferred me but I don’t know the kavachams of these deities?
